# Klein-Gordon inner product: how to make it real

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, field-theory, tensor-calculus, klein-gordon-equation

While building its way up to the construction of an inner product, one stumbles upon the following equation:
\begin{equation} \partial_i(\varphi_2^*(x)\overleftrightarrow{\partial^i}\varphi_1(x))=\partial_i(\varphi_2^*(x)\partial^i\varphi_1(x) - \varphi_1(x)\partial^i\varphi_2^*(x))=0 \end{equation}
At this point the professor defined the 4-current $J^i=i(\varphi_2^*(x)\overleftrightarrow{\partial^i}\varphi_1(x))$ so to have the conservation law
\begin{equation} \partial_iJ^i=0 \end{equation}
He stated that it's necessary to add the imaginary unit $i$ to the current so that it is real even when $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x)$.
I'm not able to understand this last clarification: shouldn't it be $J^i=0$ when $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x)$? Why is it necessary to multiply times the imaginary unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see. If $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x)$ then $J^i=i\left[\varphi^*(x)\partial^i\varphi(x) - \varphi(x)\partial^i\varphi^*(x)\right]$.

We take $\varphi(x) = exp(ikx)$ then $\varphi^*(x)=exp(-ikx)$, $\partial^i\varphi(x)=ik\ exp(ikx)$ and $\partial^i\varphi^*(x)=-ik\ exp(-ikx)$. We then put all this in J and we get:

$J^i=i(ik+ik)=-2k$

So it's true that thanks to that $i$ the current will be real in the case $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x)$.